# Passar uma imagem de uma activity para tela principal

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Como posso passar uma imagem de uma activity para outra actiivity?

Tenho uma imagem na minha tela de configurações, quero mandar ela para minha tela principal.

Salvei ela na minha sharedPreferences e gostaria de usar a key na minha outra tela, assim como faço com textos.

Activity onde estou salvando o dado (editor.putString("image", photo);)

```
public void salvarDados(){
    String usrname = edtEmailSettings.getText().toString();
    String name = edtNameField.getText().toString();
    String phone = edtPhoneField.getText().toString();
    String company = edtCompanySettings.getText().toString();
    String photo = imgProfileImage.toString();
    if(!savelogincheckbox.isChecked()){
        editor.putBoolean("savelogin",true);
        editor.putString("user",usrname);
        editor.putString("nam", name);
        editor.putString("phon", phone);
        editor.putString("company", company);
        editor.putString("image", photo);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Agora não sei como vou pegar a chave ("image") na outra activity, consigo pegar textos e mandar um setText().

Como fazer isso com imagem?

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo que passe a sua imagem através de `Intent`, no entanto, antes você deve converter a imagem para `Bitmap` e só então passá-la via Intent extras

Para passar a sua imagem da primeira activity para a que você quer, precisa fazer desta forma:

Na sua Activity de configurações:

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityAlvo.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

Recuperando na Activity Alvo:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Observação: o correto seria salvar esta imagem em algum outro lugar e recuperar passando o caminho da mesma.

Espero que tenha ajudado.